# What is the architecture of BlogEngine.net extension manager?

Tags: asp.net, blogengine.net

I was just wondering that what is the architecture of blogengine.net extension manager ?

How it loads the extension dynamically, how can I use same kind of functionality in my web applications ? so that every time i just create one class and corresponding page then just plug into the website.

Moreover I am interested to know the architecture as I didnt find any article or tutorial on it.

Any help would be appreciable.

Answer (score 2):

You can see for yourself the code is on [codeplex](http://blogengine.codeplex.com/SourceControl/ListDownloadableCommits.aspx)

Comment: I have the code but I have to conclude the architecture myself by debugging the code, so it will be like some one has given you the box of toys and now you have to figure out how to play with each type of toy ;-).

Answer (score 1):

You can read about what it is and how it works in the [wiki docs](http://blogengine.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=UsingExtensionManager&referringTitle=Home).
Blogengine uses reflection to find and instantiate types attributed as "extension" and extensions itself use event listeners to communicate with core library. Extension manager is basically API and admin front-end for all extensions running on the blog.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Plugin Pattern, have a look [here](http://www.ddj.com/cpp/184403942) how this works..